# The next section overlap the first section even using z-index

Tags: css, z-index, overlapping

I'm trying to make nav-menu to overlap every section.
But I'm trying to use z-index but it seems not to work in this situation.

I'm trying many solutions like add position for all element but still not working. 
Here is my HTML code

```html
<div class="wrap-content">
  <header class="header">
    <div class="header__center">
      <nav class="header__center--nav">
        <ul>
          <li class="main-menu"><a class="main-menu__a" href=""><span class="flaticon-right-arrow main-menu__a"></span>
                Elements</a>
            <div class="wrapper-menu">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xl-3 col-lg-3">
                  <h3>Classic</h3>
                  <div class="menu-1">
                    <ul>
                      <li> <a href="#"><span class="flaticon-right-arrow"></span>About us</a></li>
                      <li> <a href="#"><span class="flaticon-right-arrow"></span>About me</a></li>
                      <li> <a href="#"><span class="flaticon-right-arrow"></span>Contact us</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xl-3 col-lg-3">
                  <h3>Pretentation</h3>
                  <div class="menu-1">
                    <ul>
                      <li> <a href="#"><span class="flaticon-right-arrow"></span>About us</a></li>
                      <li> <a href="#"><span class="flaticon-right-arrow"></span>About me</a></li>
                      <li> <a href="#"><span class="flaticon-right-arrow"></span>Contact us</a></li>
                      <li> <a href="#"><span class="flaticon-right-arrow"></span>Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xl-3 col-lg-3">
                  <h3>Infographic</h3>
                  <div class="menu-1">
                    <ul>
                      <li> <a href="#"><span class="flaticon-right-arrow"></span>About us</a></li>
                      <li> <a href="#"><span class="flaticon-right-arrow"></span>About me</a></li>

                    </ul>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xl-3 col-lg-3">
                  <h3>Typography</h3>
                  <div class="menu-1">
                    <ul>
                      <li> <a href="#"><span class="flaticon-right-arrow"></span>About us</a></li>
                      <li> <a href="#"><span class="flaticon-right-arrow"></span>About me</a></li>
                      <li> <a href="#"><span class="flaticon-right-arrow"></span>Contact us</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </header>
  <section class="section-1">

    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6">
          <div class="col-6__inner">
            <h1>Incredible app
              <span class="col__inner--trade">features</span></h1>
            <span></span>
          </div>

          <div class="col-6__title">
            <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Illo sdam dolorem debitis quod.</h3>
          </div>

        </div>
        <div class="col-6">
          <div class="col-6__phone">
            <div class="img-phone-1">
              <img src="./img/phone-img/phone-2.png" alt="">
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```

Here is the result after I set the z-index of nav-menu is 9999.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tBPgB.png)

Comment: Can you post your CSS code as well?

Comment: If your `z-index` property has no effect, make sure the element also has a `position` property set (relative; absolute) otherwise, the z-index will not be applied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Z-index only works on positioned elements -

- position: absolute
- position: relative
- position: fixed
- position: sticky

so depending on what you are trying to do achieve, may be you need to make the Nav fixed to the top??

something like this for example:

```
nav {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 10;
}
```